# Odd String Issue in C

Tags: c, string, gethostbyname

I am writing some code that uses the function gethostbyname(). This function requires that I pass it a string of the host I am trying to find the host for. Right now I have my string declared in an array of characters, with a null byte at the end so that it is considered a string.

When I do a printf like this:`printf("\n%s\n",hostName);` the code will print correctly and say something like: `facebook.com`

However when I try to print the string like this: `printf("\n%sX\n",hostName);` the output will be `Xacebook.com` for some reason.

Does anyone know why the X would overwrite the first character of my string? I would think that it should print like "facebook.comX".

Comment: Yeah it is being read from there. Do you know how to get rid of the \r so we can supply it as an argument to gethostbyname correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You have a \r at the end of the string. That moves the cursor back to the start of the line. I'm guessing that you are reading in the hostname from a file?